# How to solve the issue in multidimensional array

Tags: php, php-5.5

I have a multidimensional array, shown below. I want to display the contents in a loop so I am using foreach loop but I am getting the error

> **Notice: Undefined index: propertyId in C:\xampp\htdocs**

How can I solve this?

```html
$proprty_id=
Array
(
    [propertyId] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
        )

    [ProprtyName] => Array
        (
            [0] => Residential Project 1 
            [1] => Residential Project 2
            [2] => Residential Property 3
            [3] => Residential Property 4
        )

)
foreach($proprty_id as $property){
    echo "ID = ".$property['propertyId']."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you define your array as `$proprty_id`
and call it as `$property`
and a few more typos maybe?

Your loop is not checking inside your array cause it has different name.

```
$property=array(
    ['propertyId'] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
        )

    ['ProprtyName'] => Array
        (
            [0] => Residential Project 1 
            [1] => Residential Project 2
            [2] => Residential Property 3
            [3] => Residential Property 4
        )

)
               foreach($property['propertyId'] as $v){

                    echo "ID = ".$v."<br>";
                }
```

Comment: 2nd edit makes more sense, it will iterate the 2nd dimension and return 1,2,3,4, alos aded quotte in array keys.